# How to clone source code of Android marshallow

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I'm trying to clone source code of Android Marshallow
from this [link](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). 
In the section

```
Initializing a Repo client
```

Third point
Run repo init to bring down the latest version of Repo with all its most recent bug fixes. **You must specify a URL for the manifest, which specifies where the various repositories included in the Android source will be placed within your working directory**.

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

So I provide this url for manifest

```
$ repo init -uhttps://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/android-6.0.1_r9
```

Then I got this

```
gpg: keyring `/home/shyam/.repoconfig/gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/home/shyam/.repoconfig/gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /home/shyam/.repoconfig/gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 920F5C65: public key "Repo Maintainer <repo@android.kernel.org>" imported
gpg: key 692B382C: public key "Conley Owens <cco3@android.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2  (RSA: 1)

Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
remote: Finding sources: 100% (15/15)
remote: Total 15 (delta 1), reused 15 (delta 1)
Unpacking objects: 100% (15/15), done.
From https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
   79fba68..8b39fb4  master     -> origin/master
Get https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/android-6.0.1_r9
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Server does not provide clone.bundle; ignoring.
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
```

Comment: try `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-6.0.1_r9` followed by `repo sync -c -j12`

Comment: @ElpieKay What is the use of this command                                               $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

Comment: https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#init

Comment: `repo init` makes a folder .repo in the current folder. And clone the git platform/manifest from -u and checkout the branch of -b into .repo/manifests. This git holds a group of manifest.xml. There is usually a default.xml which is the basic manifest. It describes how many git repos compose the whole codebase, and which revision to checkout in each repo after repo sync. By default.xml you can always sync the latest, the newest code. Besides, it holds manifests of a specific baseline, which is a revision of the whole codebase, aka the all over 400 repos.

Comment: @Michael   But when I run this  command "repo init -u android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest"    Why I'm getting this error   "curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Server does not provide clone.bundle; ignoring."

Comment: The correct url is `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`, not `android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`

Comment: @Michael Yes, I used The same url , As you mentioned. Here is the output    http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16517104/

Comment: The latest log that you pasted indicates that `repo init` succeeded. The curl error is just saying that the server doesn't support clone bundles, and can be ignored. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300245/what-to-do-about-curl-clone-bundle-error-on-aosp-repo-sync

Comment: For future reader, you may need `--repo-url  <your-downloaded-clone.bundle full path>`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646741/cannot-get-https-gerrit-googlesource-com-git-repo-clone-bundle#comment61799040_26646741